# Windows 7 says not Genuine, but everything works like it is

Tags: windows-7

In the bottom right of my desktop, I have the message saying:

Windows 7

Build 7601

This copy of Windows is not genuine

However, none of the issues that come along with that are there. The desktop wallpaper changes in its slideshow, I can do windows updates, etc. Only the annoying message on the bottom right corner of my desktop.

The only thing I can think may have caused a problem was yesterday I was changing the ntp time servers to the pool.ntp.org servers to match the time servers my Raspberry Pi is now using. Other than that, I haven't done anything that would cause this.

Restarting the computer does not help, but occasionally the message disappears off my monitors just to come back a few seconds later.

Does anyone have an idea on how to remove the message?

Comment: One vital bit of information that would help us - Is your copy of Windows 7 genuine?

Comment: Yes, I wiped my SSD and reinstalled windows a month and a half ago after I had to replace my cpu. It has been activated, and this is the first time I have seen the message.

Comment: Click `Start`, type `Activate Windows` and open the first result, can you tell us what this screen says?

Comment: CPU replacement triggered that, it is considered a different PC now, see>activate using the phone...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/activate-windows#1TC=windows-7

Comment: I said I had wiped my SSD and reinstalled windows after I replaced my cpu. Changing from AMD to Intel requires you to do that.

Comment: Also, it is telling me that windows is activated.

Comment: You should go ahead and type "slui.exe 4" into an elevated command prompt.  I also suggest you do [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-not-genuine-even-though-copy-is-purchased/84c3f2f3-a415-4024-9404-efbc0617e519?auth=1)

Comment: @Moab - A CPU replacement is not considered a different PC. Only a mobo replacement will do that.

Comment: @whs - **If the author switched from an AMD CPU to an Intel CPU that would always be the case.**

Comment: I think you are wrong if the mobo stays the same. But this case may imply that the mobo changed. I am not sure whether the AMD and Intel pins can be the same.

Comment: I first tried using the same installation of windows from AMD on my new Intel cpu + board + ddr4 ram, but it kept BSODing instantly when trying to load windows. Also, @whs Intel and AMD sockets are widely different and cannot be interchanged to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: So we can assume different mobos equal different systems.